# Distributed transaction boundary with ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

Say I have models that connect to another database:

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection {config_to_connection_to_database2}
end


class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection {config_to_connection_to_database2}
end
```

When I start a transaction, say

```
Model1.transaction do
  Model1.create! something
  Model2.create! something
  #some other thing
end
```

The SQL generated is:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO model1 ...
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO model2 ...
  COMMIT
#some other thing might happen here
COMMIT
```

When something wrong happens in `#some other thing`, `INSERT INTO model2` will not be rolled back since it's in a nested transaction and is committed already, while `INSERT INTO model1` is rolled back.

I found an ugly workaround:

```
Model1.transaction do
  Model2.transaction do
    Model1.create! something
    Model2.create! something
    #some other thing
  end
end
```

The SQL becomes:

```
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO model1 ...
    INSERT INTO model2 ...
    #some other thing might happen here
  COMMIT
COMMIT
```

which works, but a little annoying to me.

So my question is: How does activerecord decide if it should wrap a SQL statement with `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`(looks like activerecord won't bother to check if Model1 and Model2 are connecting to the same database), and is there a better workaround here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution is pretty simple(and the answer is right in the ActiveRecord::Base document, I was totally blind)

Set up a class

```
class Database2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true #this is important, otherwise the inherited class's table name would be 'database2'
  establish_connection your_connection_config
end
```

Then `Model1` and `Model2` just need to inherit `Database2`, and everything works fine.

In case anyone wonders, in this way, `Model1` and `Model2` share the same connection pool. If you call `establish_connection` in each class, then each class will have its own connection pool, which wastes resource, and will have the transaction problem mentioned in my question.